# SQL-Query return zero count if no records are found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm displaying records of a table which I `COUNT` a particular field.

There might be sometimes the table might be empty and instead of displaying a `NULL` value i want it to come zero.

```
SELECT count(comment) as total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE resp = MMColParam2 
  AND com_stat = 'No' having count(comment)> 0
```

Comment: please modify question title..

Comment: If the table is empty..... `COUNT` will always return 0. It will never return `NULL`. What makes you think it would?

Comment: WHY do you have "having count(comment)> 0" in your query?   You're not grouping by anything.   Remove this clause and the query will produce desired results.

Comment: @TabAlleman if that is removed, there is no question, that is exactly what my answer is about

Comment: As it stands, the question isn't likely to be helpful to future readers.   I'm thinking it might be useful to find out why the OP was using this filter in the first place and address that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation, you can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms184325.aspx):

> ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(comment), 0)) AS total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE resp = MMColParam2
```

Comment: isnull or coalesce will never work on a count, a count will always return an integer value from 0 and up

Answer (score 5):

You can use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), which "Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL". You pass to it **count(comment)** as the first argument, and **zero** as the second:

```
   SELECT COALESCE(count(comment), 0) as total
    FROM dbo.omment
    WHERE resp = MMColParam2
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table is empty..... `COUNT` will always return 0. It will never return `NULL`. What makes you think it would? Now that the original question has changed to include a `HAVING`, the answer is now

remove the `HAVING`

Comment: The filter was in the header. Someone deleted it instead of moving it into the query. I fixed it on @i_user's behalf

Comment: So the query has changed? and the answer is now 'remove the `having` clause'

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a CASE

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(comment) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(comment) AS total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE resp = MMColParam2
```

Comment: This is just way too convoluted. And why would you use a string literal for the `0`? It will be cast to `0` anyway, but why make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: Updated to remove literal

Answer (score 1):

checking for NULL values will not work here, because the row is not returned, and if it was, it would return 0, instead of NULL.

Very simple, delete the filter, the only thing if filters out is the value you are requesting:

```
SELECT count(comment) as total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE
  resp = MMColParam2 
  AND com_stat = 'No'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):both are same with a small difference.

> ISNULL(param1,param2): can contains only 2 parameter, and there are no
>   condition of having it's value.
>
> COALESCE (param1,param2,param3....):can contains multiple parameter,
>   and there is condition of having it's 1 value mujst not be null.

```
SELECT isnull(count(comment),0) as total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE resp = MMColParam2 

SELECT COALESCE(count(comment),0) as total
FROM dbo.omment
WHERE resp = MMColParam2
```